# How would I apply the Mid function to this string in Excel?

Tags: excel, function

I am trying to use the Mid function in Excel, but I am stuck.

In column A, there is a string that looks like this: _string_unwanted

where _ equals a space, "string" is a string of variable length that i want to extract, _ is the 2nd space, and "unwanted" is a string of variable length that i don't care about.

Here's my function:
= Mid(A1, 2, **__**)

I put "2" to start at the 2nd character spot since I want to ignore the 1st space.  What do I put in **_** such that it finds the string of variable length? Meaning, it just isolates the "string" part of the above string..and ignores the 2 spaces, and the "unwanted" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this:-

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1)
```

**Result:**

```
string_unwanted
```

### EDIT:

This is the formula:-

```
=MID(A1,2,FIND("_",A1,2)-2)
```

**Result:**

```
string
```

Comment: not quite..i think len(a1)-1..gives you the length of entire string contained in a1 minus 1 character.  so the end result is that it still contains the "unwanted" string part.  your answer successfully ignored the first space...but it still includes "unwanted"..how do  i just isolate the "string" part?

Comment: ah I see your result now.  I just want "string", and not "unwanted".  How do I do that?

Comment: wow, thanks siva.  that is exactly what i was looking for!  Thanks for your help, I couldn't have figured that one on my own.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-LEN("_unwanted")-1)
```

Comment: hi Rob, unwanted is a string of variable length.  how do I indicate that in the formula?  i think putting it in quotes means that it literally counts the length of "_unwanted", which is 9, and subtracts 1, which gives you 8.  This is not what I'm looking to do.  I just want to isolate "string".